# Trying to read 700k+ of data and the Error "GC Overhead Limit Exceeded" occurred

Tags: java, out-of-memory

Alright so I need help in reviewing my codes because I'm kinda still new in programming (currently in my second year of Diploma in Computer Science). I got this error as in the title `GC Overhead Limit Exceeded` when I tried running my code below.

A brief explanation of this code, I'm trying to read data from a CSV File and then transfer it to a database. FYI, there are actually 10 tables/CSV files that I need to read, but on this I'll show this one table `Tickets` because the error only occurred when I tried to read that table/file. The other tables have hundreds of rows/data only while the table `Tickets` have 735,504 of rows/data. Furthermore, I've succeeded in reading 450,028 of data after 6 hours of running the code before the error occurred.

What can I do to fix this error? What can be modified to improve my code? I really appreciate it if you guys can help me :)

```
public class Demo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "password";
        
        try {
            //Connect to the database
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            
            //Test on one table only
            String tableName = "Tickets";
            
            System.out.println("Connecting to TABLE " +tableName +"...");
            readCSVFile(tableName, connection);
            
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("THE END");

            connection.close();//close connection to the database
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR at main(): SQLException!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    static int countNewRow = 0;
    static int countUpdatedRow = 0;
    
    //Method to read the CSV File
    static void readCSVFile(String tableName, Connection conn) {
        
        //Read CSV File
        try {
            String path = tableName +".csv";
            
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            br.readLine();//skip the first line
            String inData;
            
            //Read The Remaining Line
            while((inData=br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] rowData = inData.split(",");
                ArrayList <String> rowDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
                
                for (int i=0; i<rowData.length; i++)
                    rowDataList.add(rowData[i]);
                
                
                //To combine String that starts and ends with "
                for(int i=0; i<rowDataList.size(); i++) {
                    if (rowDataList.get(i).charAt(0) == '"') {
                        String string1 = rowDataList.get(i).substring(1, rowDataList.get(i).length());
                        String string2 = rowDataList.get(i+1).substring(0, rowDataList.get(i+1).length()-1);
                        String combined = string1 +"," +string2;
                        
                        rowDataList.set(i, combined); 
                        rowDataList.remove(i+1);
                        
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                
                //Remove the RM
                for(int i=0; i<rowDataList.size(); i++) {
                    if (rowDataList.get(i).startsWith("RM")) {
                        String string = rowDataList.get(i).substring(2);
                        rowDataList.set(i, string);
                    }
                }
                
                //This is just to keep track of the data that has been read
                System.out.println("[" +rowDataList.get(0) +"]");
                
                //Transfer the data to the database
                insertToDatabase(conn, tableName, rowDataList);
            }
            
            System.out.println("New Row Added : " +countNewRow);
            System.out.println("Updated Row   : " +countUpdatedRow);
            System.out.println("== Process Completed ==");
            br.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR at readCSVFile(): FileNotFoundException!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR at readCSVFile(): IOException!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR at readCSVFile(): SQLException!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR at readCSVFile(): ParseException!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    
    static void insertToDatabase(Connection connection, String tableName, ArrayList <String> rowDataList) throws SQLException, ParseException {
        
        String tableIdName = tableName;
        if (tableIdName.charAt(tableIdName.length()-1) == 's')
            tableIdName = tableIdName.substring(0, tableIdName.length()-1);
        
        //To read row
        String rowID = rowDataList.get(0);
        String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM " +tableName +" "
                          +"WHERE " +tableIdName +"_ID = " +rowID;
        
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
        
        boolean value = result.next();
        
        //INSERT @ UPDATE row
        if (value == true) { //Update Row if the data is already existed
            updateStatementt(tableName, connection, rowDataList);
            countUpdatedRow++;
        }
        else { //Insert New Row
            insertStatementt(tableName, connection, rowDataList);
            countNewRow++;
        }
    }
    
    //Method to insert data to the database
    static void insertStatementt(String tableType, Connection conn, ArrayList <String> rowDataList) throws SQLException, ParseException {
        
        //Generate Question Mark
        String generateQuestionMark = null;
        
        if(rowDataList.size() == 1)
            generateQuestionMark = "?";
        else
            generateQuestionMark = "?, ";
        
        for(int i=1; i<rowDataList.size(); i++) {
            if(i!=rowDataList.size()-1)
                generateQuestionMark += "?, ";
            else
                generateQuestionMark += "?";
        }
        
        //Insert sql
        String sql = "INSERT INTO " +tableType +" VALUES (" +generateQuestionMark +")";
        
        PreparedStatement insertStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        
        //Insert data

        //There are other 'if' and 'else if' statements here for other tables

        else if (tableType.equals("Tickets")) {
            int ticketID = Integer.parseInt(rowDataList.get(0));
            int movieId = Integer.parseInt(rowDataList.get(1));
            int theaterId = Integer.parseInt(rowDataList.get(2));
            String[] date = rowDataList.get(3).split("/");
            String dateString = date[2] +"-" +date[1] +"-" +date[0];
            Date showDate = Date.valueOf(dateString);
            int showTimeId = Integer.parseInt(rowDataList.get(4));
            int cptId = Integer.parseInt(rowDataList.get(5));
            int pcId = Integer.parseInt(rowDataList.get(6));
            float amountPaid = Float.parseFloat(rowDataList.get(7));
            int year = Integer.parseInt(rowDataList.get(8));
            String month = rowDataList.get(9);
            
            insertStatement.setInt(1, ticketID);
            insertStatement.setInt(2, movieId);
            insertStatement.setInt(3, theaterId);
            insertStatement.setDate(4, showDate);
            insertStatement.setInt(5, showTimeId);
            insertStatement.setInt(6, cptId);
            insertStatement.setInt(7, pcId);
            insertStatement.setFloat(8, amountPaid);
            insertStatement.setInt(9, year);
            insertStatement.setString(10, month);
        }
        
        insertStatement.executeUpdate();        
        insertStatement.close();
    }
    
    
    //Method to update the data from the database
    static void updateStatementt(String tableType, Connection conn, ArrayList <String> rowDataList) throws SQLException {
        Statement  statement = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "UPDATE " +tableType;
                
        //There are other 'if' and 'else if' statements here for other tables
        
        else if (tableType.equals("Tickets")) {
            String[] date = rowDataList.get(3).split("/");
            String dateString = date[2] +"-" +date[1] +"-" +date[0];
            
            sql += " SET movie_id = " +rowDataList.get(1) +","
                +  " theater_id = " +rowDataList.get(2) +","
                +  " showdate = \"" +dateString +"\","
                +  " showtime_id = " +rowDataList.get(4) +","
                +  " costperticket_id = " +rowDataList.get(5) +","
                +  " personcategory_id = " +rowDataList.get(6) +","
                +  " amount_paid = " +rowDataList.get(7) +","
                +  " year = " +rowDataList.get(8) +","
                +  " month = \"" +rowDataList.get(9) +"\""
                +  " WHERE ticket_id = " +rowDataList.get(0);
        }
        
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably run out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `statement.close()` for the update Statement.

Answer (score 1):

For short, read a single line and do whatever you want to do with it. You don't have enough memory for all 700k lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to read all this data into the Java heap, increase the heap size using, for example, the `-Xmx` command-line switch. Because of the way textual data is encoded in the JVM, you'll probably need much more heap that the total data size would suggest.

In addition, there might be some places in your code where you can take the strain off the JVM's memory management system. For example, concatenating strings using "+" can generate a lot of temporary data, which will increase the load on the garbage collector. Assembling strings using a `StringBuilder` might be a simple, less resource-hungry, alternative.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the usage of `StringBuilder` anywhere on my code please? I'm sorry because I've never used that thing before.

Comment: Rather than doing "String s = a + b + c....", do "StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(); s.append(a); s.append(b); b.append(c);...."